# Help with Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Our differential equation is:
>   $$
> y' + 2y/3 = 1-t/2
> $$
>   Consider $y_0$ and find the value for which the solution of our differential equation touches, but does not cross, the $t$-axis.

*EDIT*

I've resolved the original discrepancy that spurned this question. However, I'm having trouble answering the actual question above. That is, I am having trouble finding the point at which Y touches, but does not cross, the t-axis and solving for the solution.

I have solved for $y=-3t/4+(21/8)+Ce^{-2t/3}$. This is correct, as confirmed by other posters below.

Must I input this into some program like Matlab or can I answer this question using only pen and paper?

Comment: I can answer any questions about my work. However, posting it here would take me a significant amount of time because I am still very new.  So, please, forgive the lack of work shown here and please let me know if I can provide any information that will help you all help me!

Comment: What value of $y$ are you getting? I can post my work at a solution if that helps

Comment: I've not followed through and solved for the value of y that answers the questions because, at the halfway mark, it seems that I am diverging from the supposed solution.

Comment: Substitute in the DE to see whether it works. It does not appear to.

Comment: @adriano - thanks for the help!

Comment: The homogeneous part is correct. Can you show us how you got the $\frac{9}{4}t - \frac{9}{4}$ part? Are you using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients?

Comment: I think the mistake may have happened when I was dealing with the unknown function values early on. I had $e^(2t/3)y= integral       e^(2t/3)(1-(t/2))$     I distributed the exponential term and then split that into two integrals. The first was straight forward and the second I solved using integration by parts.

Comment: For linear ODE, go an learn some Laplace transform.

Comment: @Troy Woo - The professor assigned this problem at the end of our second lecture. I assume we will cover Laplace transforms later this semester. Maybe I will try and sneak ahead of the class and learn some of it on my own to make my life a bit more simple?

Comment: @mathtastic Laplace transform is sort of no brainer. But I guess you still need to go through elementary analytical skills to gain some insight into the field. Feeling is more important for mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential term that gives the general solution of the homogeneous equation is right. Now we look for a particular solution of the form $y=at+b$.

Substituting, we get the equations $a+\frac{2}{3}b=1$ and $\frac{2}{3}a=-\frac{1}{2}$. Solve. The answer is different from yours.

**Remark:** *Solving* an equation can be difficult. But *checking* whether a claimed solution is indeed a solution is generally easy.

**Added:**  Now that you have the general solution, you only need to find $C$. Where the curve touches the $t$-axis, we have $y=0$. We also have $y'=0$ there, because of the "touch" part.  That gives $1-t/2=0$, so the time is given by $t=2$. Now substitute in the general solution, and solve for $C$.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't think about just taking the derivative of my purported function and checking if it satisfied the D.E. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I am making some simple mistake somewhere during integration.

Comment: The method I sketched gives an easy path to the answer. It is sometimes called the Method of Undetermined Coefficients. You used a different method, Integrating Factors. Yes, the slip is probably a simple one, my guess is that it is while integrating $e^{-2t/3}$ you lost a constant factor. But I cannot be sure without seeing the details.

Comment: I've found my error. However, I'm unsure how to solve the actual problem - finding a solution that touches but does not cross the t-axis.  Is my only hope to use some program to plot this with different values of C?

Comment: You have the general formula, you only need to find $C$. Where it touches, we have $y=0$. We also have $y'=0$ there. That gives $1-t/2=0$, so the time is $t=2$. Now substitute in the solution, and solve for $C$.

Comment: Got it all worked out! Thanks for the help, Andre.

Comment: You are welcome.